# How to choose a fallback font?

Tags: c#, winforms, fonts, fallback

We generate some text that use specified font. If there is no such character in the specified font, font flalback replace it with other one. On export to other formats(for instance PDF) we need to know what characters are missed in specified font and what font should we use to take missed characters and show the text correctly.

It's possible to get the missed characters using Uniscribe, but how to know when could we find missed characters. We can't go through all fonts in search for right one because there could be hundred fonts installed. Even if we find and font with necessary characters we need to choose the most appropriate.

Comment: To select a "similar" font, you will definitely have to go through a list of candidate fonts.

Comment: And how to get this list of candidate fonts? For example, for Beresta font?

Comment: All installed fonts are candidates.

Comment: We don't need any appropriate font. We need to know the name of that font which is used at font fallback.